# How to efficiently extract a sub array based upon a set of keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays $data.

With

```
print_r($data);
```

returning

```
Array ( 
[1401] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 2 [2] => 159 ) 
[1402] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 2 [2] => 50 [3] => 23 [4] => 159 ) 
[1403] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 2 [2] => 50 ) 
[1404] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 90 [2] => 50 [3] => 23 ) 
[1405] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 90 ) 
[1406] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 90 [2] => 23 ) 
[1407] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 90 [2] => 50 )
)
```

The keys are a set of numbers. And I need to extract from this array a sub array which has only the keys stored in another variable.

```
$toextract=array(1402,1406);
```

Apart building one by one the new array with a loop, is there a simpler way. I will need to run this command multiple times so it is quite important that is fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $result = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip(array(1402, 1406));
```

[`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array-intersect-key)

Comment: array_flip! That's what I was missing.

Comment: Even without `array_flip()` it's super simple to create an array with given keys ;) `$r = array(); foreach(array(1402, 1406) as $k) $r[$k] = null;` Just said